# Symfony: How to get a null parameter from the request

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4, url-parameters

I'm trying to build an action in symfony that recieves a list of parameters from the request this way:

```
$param = $request->getParameter('param_name');
```

The problem is that sometimes i need this parameters to be null, but when i request an url like `mySfProject.com/sfproject/module1/action/param1//param2//param3/notNull/` the action gets "param2" as the value of "param1".

I create this urls with the symfony `link_to` or `url_for` functions btw.

Is what i'm trying to do possible? could you help me? Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: Сan you post part of your routing.yml and your link_to  or url_for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could wrap values with parenthesis to avoid this. your url would be:

```
mySfProject.com/sfproject/module1/action/param1/()/param2/()/param3/(notNull)/
```